# I am having problems displaying python code because I get _tkinter.TclError

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I want to run a python code that will use the Turtle graphics module to make a graphical presentation of my code. I'm doing this in a Linux guest (VM) and windows host using vagrant.
In my vagrantfile, I have added:
`config.ssh.forward_agent = 'true' config.ssh.forward_x11 = 'true'`
I have uncommented line in /etc/ssh/ssh_config that said # ForwardX11 no and changed no to yes.
I even installed and ran vcXsrv and tried to start the VM with it running. Didn't work.

I still get:

```
             . . .

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 3679, in __init__
    _Screen._root = self._root = _Root()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 435, in __init__
    TK.Tk.__init__(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2270, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

I then exported DISPLAY=localhost:0.0 and got:

```
     . . .
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 435, in __init__
    TK.Tk.__init__(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2270, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "localhost:0.0"
```

I know there are many Qs&As that address similar issues eg if you are using WSL but none covers what I should do if I'm using a VM.

Comment: The Linux VM does not start a desktop environment?

Comment: No, it doesn't start a desktop environment.

Comment: Then you need to connect the Linux VM via ssh with X forwarding enabled (`ssh -X ...`) and X-server running in Windows host.

Comment: I tried that too. Doesn't work.

Comment: The X11 forwarding cannot be setup properly using `vagrant ssh`.  Use PuTTY to connect the VM with X11 forwarding.  Also set `X11UseLocalhost no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K52xf.png) is the image showing X11 forwarding using MobaXterm (with built-in X-Server) successfully.